# How to traverse array from both left to right and from right to left?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traversal

Suppose I have an imperative algorithm that keeps two indices `left` and `right` and moves them from left to right and from right to left

```
var left  = 0
var right = array.length - 1
while (left < right) { .... } // move left and right inside the loop
```

Now I would like to write this algorithm *without* mutable indices. 
How can I do that ? Do you have any examples of such algorithms ? I would prefer a non-recursive approach.

Comment: You could use a recursive approach...

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks. I would prefer a non-recursive approach though.

Comment: If you want to use a loop, you will have to alter any variable (at least some helpervariable), in order to get the exit-condition. Btw. why don't you want to use recursion? That is the functional way of doing stuff with immutable values! (Please update your question)

Comment: either you have to use recursion or mutable indexes. How else are you able to remember what element you are processing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map pairs of elements between your list and its reverse, then go from left to right through that list of pairs and keep taking as long as your condition is satisfied:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val zipped = list zip list.reverse
val filtered = zipped takeWhile { case (a, b) => (a < b) }
```

Value of `filtered` is `List((1, 5), (2, 4))`.
Now you can do whatever you need with those elements:

```
val result = filtered map {
  case (a, b) => 
    // do something with each left-right pair, e.g. sum them
    a + b
}

println(result) // List(6, 6)
```

If you need some kind of context dependant operation (that is, each
   iteration depends on the result of the previous one) then you have to
   use a more powerful abstraction (monad), but let's not go there if
   this is enough for you. Even better would be to simply use recursion, as pointed out by others, but you said that's not an option.

EDIT:

Version without extra pass for reversing, only constant-time access for elem(length - index):

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val zipped = list.view.zipWithIndex
val filtered = zipped takeWhile { case (a, index) => (a < list(list.length - 1 - index)) }

println(filtered.toList)  // List((1, 0), (2, 1))

val result = filtered map {
  case (elem, index) => // do something with each left-right pair, e.g. sum them
    val (a, b) = (elem, list(list.length - 1 - index))
    a + b
}

println(result.toList) // List(6, 6)
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `reverse`. However it adds one more array pass to the algorithm. I am wondering if I can do the `reverse` lazily using a `view/stream` for instance.

Comment: In terms of complexity you're at O(n) anyway. Is the list really that large?

Comment: @Michael: If you want to access the elements by their indices (like in the imperative version in your question), maybe `val r = 0 to (a.length - 1); val indices = r zip r.reverse; r.map {case (left, right) => …}` might be worth considering?

Comment: @Marth there's also `zipWithIndex` that you can invoke on a zipped list of pairs. That way you get a `List[(Int, Int), Int]` which has pairs on _1 and indexes on _2

Comment: @slouc Thanks for the update. The list is not that large. That's kind of theoretical question.

Comment: @Michael To have laziness you can use `reverseIterator` instead of `reverse`: `array.iterator zip array.reverseIterator`

Comment: @Kolmar `reverseIterator` is a good idea ! However iterators are mutable state, aren't they ?

Comment: @Michael I don't mean to be "that guy", but what exactly are we doing here? You got plenty of responses, plenty of valid ideas and solutions, and plenty of discussions. To quote StackOverflow: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?". If your question has not been answered with an acceptable answer, please update it and we'll be happy to provide a complete solution to your problem. SO is meant as a concrete question - concrete answer kind of thing, not "give me 1000 options for achieving this and then let's discuss them".

Comment: @slouc You are right. I will post a follow-up concrete question with a specific example.

Comment: @Michael Great! Sorry if I sounded harsh but we need to maintain some order here :) I'd be happy to get involved in a discussion, just not here. If you come up with a follow-up question, I'd love to see it. Feel free to tag me.

Comment: @slouc. Posted a new concrete question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42306911/521070

Answer (score 3):

Use `reverseIterator`:

```
scala> val arr = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> arr.iterator.zip(arr.reverseIterator).foreach(println)
(1,5)
(2,4)
(3,3)
(4,2)
(5,1)
```

This function is efficient on `IndexedSeq` collections, which `Array` is implicitly convertible to.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what needs to be done at each iteration, but here's something to think about.

```
array.foldRight(0){case (elem, index) =>
  if (index < array.length/2) {
    /* array(index) and elem are opposite elements in the array */
    /* do whatever (note: requires side effects) */
    index+1
  } else index // do nothing
} // ignore result
```

Upside: Traverse the array only once and no mutable variables.

Downside: Requires side effects (but that was implied in your example). Also, it'd be better if it traversed only half the array, but that would require early breakout and Scala doesn't offer an easy/elegant solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    myarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    rmyarray  = myarray[::-1]
    
    Final_Result = []
    
    for i in range(len(myarray)//2):
        Final_Result.append(myarray[i])
        Final_Result.append(rmyarray[i])
    
    print(Final_Result)

# This is the simple approach I think .
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. And, since this is an old question, please explain how it compliments other answers.