# Functional way to find a pair of integers, which sum to X, in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala, functional-programming

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272546/how-to-traverse-array-from-both-left-to-right-and-from-right-to-left).
Suppose I want to find a pair of integers, which sum to a given number `x`, in a given sorted array. The well-known "one pass" solution looks like that:

```
def pair(a: Array[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {

  var l = 0
  var r = a.length - 1
  var result: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
  while (l < r && result.isEmpty) {
    (a(l), a(r)) match {
      case (x, y) if x + y == target => result = Some(x, y)
      case (x, y) if x + y < target => l = l + 1
      case (x, y) if x + y > target => r = r - 1
    }
  }
  result
}
```

How would you suggest write functionally without any mutable state ?
I guess I can write a recursive version with `Stream` (lazy list in Scala)
Could you suggest a non-recursive version ?

Comment: This code will not compile with Scala.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to compile and fix it.

Comment: Hi @Michael. Fixed that for you. Regarding answer, I see that there are plenty already :)

Comment: Why non-recursive? The pure equivalent to a loop is recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward version.  It creates a `Stream` of `Vectors` that removes the first or last element on each iteration.  Then we limit the size of the otherwise infinite `Stream` (-1 so you can't add a number with itself), then `map` it into the output format and check for the target condition.

```
def findSum(a: Vector[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  def stream = Stream.iterate(a){
    xs => if (xs.head + xs.last > target) xs.init else xs.tail
  }

  stream.take (a.size - 1)
        .map {xs => (xs.head, xs.last)}
        .find {case (x,y) => x + y == target}
}
```

There are a lot of gems hidden in the companion objects of Scala's collections, like `Stream.iterate`.  I highly recommend checking them out.  Knowing about them can greatly simplify a problem like this.

Comment: Thanks ! Did not know about `Stream.iterate`.

Comment: Very nice. I like the way it separates out producing the stream of candidates from testing whether we have a match.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that doesn't use indices (which I try to avoid unless there's an important computation with the value of them):

```
def findPair2(x: Int, a: Array[Int]): Option[(Int, Int)] = {   
    def findPairLoop(x: Int, l: Array[Int], r: Array[Int]): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
        if (l.head >= r.last) None
        else if (l.head + r.last == x) Some((l.head, r.last))
        else if (l.head + r.last > x) findPairLoop(x, l, r.init)
        else findPairLoop(x, l.tail, r)
    }
    findPairLoop(x, a, a)
}
```

It's recursive, but doesn't need Stream. `tail` and `init` are O(N) for Array but if we use Lists and reverse the `r` collection to avoid `init` and `last` an O(N) version can be done

```
  def findPairInOrderN(x: Int, a: Array[Int]): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
    def findPairLoop(x: Int, l: List[Int], r: List[Int]): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
        if (l.head >= r.head) None
        else if (l.head + r.head == x) Some((l.head, r.head))
        else if (l.head + r.head > x) findPairLoop(x, l, r.tail)
        else findPairLoop(x, l.tail, r)
    }
    val l = a.toList
    findPairLoop(x, l, l.reverse)
}
```

If we don't care about one-pass (or efficiency generally :)) it's a one liner

```
(for (m <-a ; n <- a if m + n == x) yield (m,n)).headOption
```

unwrapping that into flatmap/map and then using collectFirst gives us this, which is fairly neat and more optimal (but still not O(n)) - it stops at the first correct pair but does more work than necessary to get there.

```
 a.collectFirst{case m => a.collectFirst{case n if n+m == x => (m,n)}}.get
```

Comment: And `Array.tail` is actually `O(n)` in Scala. So... this answer is also `O(n^2)`.

Comment: `Array.tail` is actually inherited from `IndexedSeqOptimized`. And is defined at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L128 which uses `slice` defined at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L109

Comment: So, use `Vector`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, see the update for one that really is O(N).

Comment: Why use `.tail` anyways ? Why do you even want to deform a one pass linear time algorithm just for the sake of using `.tail` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Eh? The `tail` does exactly the same function as the +1 in the indices based approach. It's not "deforming" anything, it's just another approach to moving along the list. And it is (in it's O(N) variant) still a "one pass linear time algorithm". I think you're looking for reasons to be picky.

Comment: Though, I will agree to this `I think you're looking for reasons to be picky`. But I have a good reason and that is we are complicating a very simple and efficient program for some strangely un-known reason.

Comment: It's not more complicated, it's just different. And given the OP has said this is a follow up to a previous question which, if you care to look, is exactly about avoiding the use of indices, the reason is neither strange or unknown. Apart from the conversion to List, the efficiency is pretty much identical to your indices version.

Comment: The only issue that I had with your solution was `Array.tail` which makes it `O(n^2)`. I do not have any other disagreement with your solution as long as you mention this in your answer.

Comment: I have already provided an O(N) version and said it was that. I don't really see the need to be even more specfic but if you insist...

Comment: As OP wanted a `non-recursive` solution, my answer is pretty much useless here. The reason I have not deleted it, is just for the sake of advising OP to not use `return` like this in Scala. Also, OP wanted to avoid "mutable" indices. Not indices altogether.

Comment: No, the OP asked for two things: functionally, without mutable state, and also non-recursive. Personally, I think idiomatic functional code does not use explicit indices except where really necessary. But I'm out of here, it's late.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion and without a mutable state it can get pretty ugly. Here's my attempt:

```
def f(l: List[Int], x: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  l.foldLeft(l.reverse) {
    (list, first) =>
      list.headOption.map {
        last =>
          first + last match {
            case `x` => return Some(first, last)
            case sum if sum < x => list
            case sum if sum > x =>
              val innerList = list.dropWhile(_ + first > x)
              innerList.headOption.collect {
                case r if r + first == x => return Some(first, r)
              }.getOrElse {
                innerList
              }
          }
      }.getOrElse {
        return None
      }
  }
  None
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> f(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 3)
res33: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))

scala> f(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 9)
res34: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((4,5))

scala> f(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 12)
res36: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
```

The `.reverse` in the beginning plus the `foldLeft` with a return when the result is found makes this `O(2n)`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136038/discussion-on-answer-by-nmat-functional-way-to-find-a-pair-of-integers-which-su).

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner

```
[ (x, y) | x <- array, y <- array, x+y == n ]
```

It even works on unsorted lists.

But if you want to take advantage of the sorting, just do a binary search for `(n-x)` for every `x` in the array instead of going through the array.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would've reached for. It would be to everyone's benefit to provide an explanation of what's going on behind the scenes and why that makes this an ideal solution (compared to the others presented). Hint to readers: no, it's not better just because it's syntactically shorter.

Comment: This is supposed to be in Scala

Comment: Everyone knows how to do this in O(n^2).  You've missed the point of the question, which is to make an O(n) algorithm.  Also, adding an element with itself isn't allowed, so `array = [1..1000000]` and `n = 2` should return no results fairly quickly.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I didn't miss that point, see my last paragraph. The problem of the OT was how to do such things without mutation. I showed an initial pure functional solution that can be refined. For example, we can refine `x <- array` to `x <- dropWhile (<n) array` and so on. The additional requirement that an x cannot be paired with itself, despite not stated in the original question, can also easily be fullfilled.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt It must of course be `takeWhile` instead of `dropWhile`. Sorry for the mistake.